# Counting Character Occurrences for Each Pandas Dataframe Record

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, count

I have a data frame with a row that looks like the following:

```
Section Title                          ...
==========================================
4.1.1   4.1.1 Requirements allocation. ...
4.1.2   4.1.2 Safety.                  ...
4.1.3   4.1.3 Warnings.                ...
```

I am trying to count the number of periods (.) in the Section column, so I wrote this line:

```
df['Subsections'] = df.Section.str.count(".")
```

However, the subsections column is returning the number 5 rather than the number I would expect for the first record which is 2 since there are two periods (.). Is there some little nuance I am missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design [`Series.str.count(pat, flags=0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html#pandas-series-str-count) interpret  `pat` parameter as a regular expression pattern(See the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/87cfe4e38bafe7300a6003a1d18bd80f3f77c763/pandas/core/strings/object_array.py#L102)). So you need to explicitly escape the `.` character using `\` to literally match with `.`

```
>>> df.Section.str.count("\.")
```